# Using regions inside of included Pages

Tags: dxa, dxa-1.5

I created my own regions which I can use without issues inside of a normal page.

However, once I try to use them in my included pages I get the following error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/Views/Toerisme/Region/Header.jsp at line 12

12:     <dxa:region name="Toerisme:Logo"/>
13: 
14:     <button class="sitemenu-trigger" aria-controls="mainnav" aria-expanded="false"><span
15:             class="vlbr-icon icon-menu"></span><span class="sr-only">Open menu</span></button>


Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:584) [jasper.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:481) [jasper.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385) [jasper.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329) [jasper.jar:8.5.5]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:726) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:592) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:526) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:229) [spring-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262) [spring-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180) [spring-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950) [spring-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852) [spring-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882) [spring-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778) [spring-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:726) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:592) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:526) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:887) ~[jasper.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:647) ~[jasper.jar:8.5.5]
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.markup.AbstractMarkupTag.decorateInclude(AbstractMarkupTag.java:91) ~[dxa-common-api-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.taglib.dxa.RegionTag.doStartTag(RegionTag.java:144) ~[dxa-common-impl-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.Views.Toerisme.Page.ToerismeHomePage_jsp._jspx_meth_dxa_005fregion_005f0(ToerismeHomePage_jsp.java:340) [ROOT/:na]
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.Views.Toerisme.Page.ToerismeHomePage_jsp._jspService(ToerismeHomePage_jsp.java:208) [ROOT/:na]
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) [jasper.jar:8.5.5]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443) [jasper.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385) [jasper.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329) [jasper.jar:8.5.5]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-websocket.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:726) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:469) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:394) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238) [spring-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262) [spring-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180) [spring-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950) [spring-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852) [spring-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882) [spring-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778) [spring-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-websocket.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at com.tridion.ambientdata.web.AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter.doFilter(AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter.java:286) [web-ambient-client-8.2.0-1005.jar:8.2.0-1005]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88) [spring-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76) [spring-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.5]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.5.5]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_101]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.taglib.dxa.RegionTag.doStartTag(RegionTag.java:113) ~[dxa-common-impl-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.Views.Toerisme.Region.Header_jsp._jspx_meth_dxa_005fregion_005f0(Header_jsp.java:258) ~[ROOT/:na]
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.Views.Toerisme.Region.Header_jsp._jspService(Header_jsp.java:141) ~[ROOT/:na]
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) [jasper.jar:8.5.5]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443) [jasper.jar:8.5.5]
    ... 81 common frames omitted
```

**My page is included in the following manner**:

**Page Template:**
[image]
**Main Page**: 
[image]
**Included Header Page**
[image]
The Header is accessed in the following manner from the main Page (which works, when the Logo region is not added to the Header)

```
<dxa:region name="Toerisme:Header"/>
```

Inside the Included Header page, the logo region is loaded as follows:

```
<dxa:region name="Logo"/>
```

The Logo Region is Composed as follows: 
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Region names are normally unqualified (e.g. just "Header" instead of "Toerisme:Header").

Furthermore, for include Pages, the (unqualified) Region Name and (qualified) Region View Name is derived from the Page Title.

I see you're using qualified Region names in the `dxa:regiom` tag and in the PT metadata. Furthermore, you're predefining the `Toerisme:Header` Region in PT metadata.

You didn't mention what the title is of your Header include Page, but I guess you have two Regions in your Page Model: `Header` representing the include Page and `Toerisme:Header` representing your predefined Region. The latter will be empty, but that one gets rendered by the `<dxa:region name="Toerisme:Header"/>` tag.

A nice debugging technique which you can use to (dis)prove this theory is to request the Page with `?format=json` in the URL. That returns a JSON representation of the Page Model (so it doesn't get rendered using Views).

Comment: I was indeed loading 2 Regions: Header and Toerisme:Header

Comment: The include is loading the correct Header region now, including the Logo. I am wondering though, how does it know that it needs to load the Header from the 'Toerisme' Module and not from Core? How would you specify that using the Header page title?

Comment: Looked more into it and the wrong Header (from Core instead of Toerisme Module) is indeed being loaded now. How do I specify the Module from which to load the Header inside the Page title?

Comment: Changed the page title to be Toerisme:Header. Accessing by <dxa:region name="Header"/>. This loads Header from the correct module so I'm assuming this is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Yes, that is indeed the way to do it: let the include Page title be the qualified Region View Name; the Region Name becomes the same, but unqualified (i.e. excluding the Module/Area name).